# How to insert pdf double spread (without blank pages or odd page breaks)?

Tags: pdfpages

I'd like to insert a two-page pdf as a double-spread, i.e. on facing pages, but with page breaks otherwise unaffected. I realise that I could do this just by inserting the pdf pages into the latex-produced pdf, but I'd prefer to do this from with latex. This shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\includepdf[pages=-]{twopagespread}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here twopagespread.pdf is a two-page pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the command `\afterpage` from *afterpage* package. `\afterpage{\includepdf[pages=-]{twopagespread}}`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\afterpage{\includepdf[pages=-]{twopagespread}}
\section{Foo bar}
\lipsum
\section{Bar foo}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you look for an automatic solution you can do

```
\afterpage{%
\ifodd\value{page}
\afterpage{\includepdf[pages=-]{twopagespread}}
\else
\includepdf[pages=-]{twopagespread}
\fi}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]%\lipsum[1-7]
\afterpage{%
\ifodd\value{page}
\afterpage{\includepdf[pages=-]{twopagespread}}
\else
\includepdf[pages=-]{twopagespread}
\fi}
\section{Foo bar}
\lipsum
\section{Bar foo}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```